# I am a restricted user and can't comment on an answer

Tags: support, questions, comments

I can't ask new questions at this point, but have a similar problem that relates to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/47424/187421). I also can't sent private messages. Now what can I do?

Edit: so how do I add a question? It's strange that I already have 47 points and I can't add a question? :(

Edit 2: It's obvious to me there is not private messaging system here.

Comment: There is no private message system here.

Comment: If you can't add a question, you will get a message that clearly explains why this is the case and what to do in that the situation.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a new question, you have to [ask a new question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). Link to the other post as well so that the context of your issue is clear. If you can't ask questions anymore, you will have to work on having that ban removed, sorry.

I don't see how adding a comment to the answer would help you (or others) in the long run. If you have an issue, the fastest way to get it solved is by asking a question.

If you really want to add a comment, you have to wait [until you have 50 reputation](https://superuser.com/privileges/comment), then you can do so. There's no working around that restriction, really. Moderators can convert answers to comments, but this should be used in special cases, and not to help users work around their missing privilege.

Comment: Probably question blocked.

Comment: 8/14 questions are deleted..

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are question banned.  See [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers) (on Meta Stack Overflow) for more information.  In order to release the ban, you need to improve your existing questions.

If there is a question you want to improve that has been deleted, or if you want a list of your deleted questions, you can flag any of your existing posts for moderator attention using the free-text option and ask for what you need.  If you need assistance with improving a question, you can use the [Root Access](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access) or [Ask a Super User Moderator](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/114/ask-a-super-user-moderator) chat rooms, and post the content of the question and what you need help on.  The community moderators are happy to assist you with restoring your account back to good standing.  The [About](https://superuser.com/about) and [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq) pages will help you write better questions.

To start, I have edited and voted to reopen your question https://superuser.com/questions/533456/how-do-i-easily-check-if-the-no-referrers-setting-is-working-in-my-browser so that it can be more easily understood.

Comment: While we can surely help a user undeleting questions, note that the OP has more than half of their questions deleted, which is quite a lot. At least four of those aren't salvageable at all.

Comment: I have upvoted two of the OP's questions and the user's only answer.  I think this is a good-faith user who doesn't fully understand the rules, and I feel the user deserves a chance.

Comment: Update: I had to retract one of the votes, because I don't want my voting to be seen as fraudulent.  I'm trying to help, but I want to make sure that every vote is in fact deserved.

Comment: You may vote however you like according to the value of posts – no need to retract a few votes – this is up to you. We can also of course help the OP have questions undeleted that could be fixed. However, as even moderators have no direct information about the account status with regard to question bans, we can't give more specific advice.